# how to get Xcode breakpoints jumped to directly (C++ the language)

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I am new to write C++ with Xcode and was working on some simple problem with two files, main.cpp and one class implementation respectively.

The thing is, when I clicked Run and expected it got paused at a breakpoint I placed in the context of a function member of the solution class, the execution just passed by.

But when I placed another breakpoint in the corresponding calling line in the main function and tried 'step into' from there, I got myself into the member function, yet when I clicked 'continue' after that, jumped right to the end again, rather than to the first breakpoint I placed.

I have been searching for solution here for a while but to no avail. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive that it should hit your breakpoint? Is it within an `if` or some other flow control structure that may not be entered? We can only guess without seeing your code and what line you are trying to hit.

Comment: Yes I am sure with that. Actually I have figured out the solution to hit it as long as I separated my class into head and implementation files. I thought I didnt have to cause the class was so small. || P.S. I can't upload any images cause I am freshman here without sufficient reputation credits. Sorry about that, and thanks a lot~